# How can I install Git to my server which does not have apt-get?

Tags: linux, git

My host is Bluehost. My server is on Linux.

I have tried to follow [the tutorial](http://www.urbanpuddle.com/articles/2008/07/11/installing-git-on-a-server-ubuntu-or-debian).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can quite easily compile it from source, with the usual `./configure && make && sudo make install` commands.

See ["How to install git"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide/323764#323764). Specifically the Mac OS X section (which applies to Linux also)

Answer (score 5):

If the machine doesn't have apt-get, then chances are it isn't a Debian or Ubuntu machine, which means that using a tutorial designed for Debian or Ubuntu is unlikely to get you very far.

Either use the packaged releases for whatever Linux distribution you *are* running, or build from source.

Answer (score 0):

Get the source from http://git.or.cz/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have the same problem I have that I cannot have an outgoing connection but I can have an incoming connection, that´s why I cannot use apt-get. What I do to move files is just use WinSCP and move the files there and after do whatever I want with them.